# JS: Slideshow inaccurate result

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

Hi I write this simple javascript slideshow cause I want to write my own slideshow in javascript. It automatically change the images by a set time interval. But when I try to click the backward and forward function the result is not accurate or the images are in order.

```js
 var images = ["http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/1.jpg","http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/2.jpg","http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/3.jpg"];

 var i = 0;
 var count = images.length; 
 
 function slidingImages() 
 {
   i = i % count;
   document.banner.src = images[i];
   i++;
 }
 
 function forward()
  {
   i = (i + 1) % count;
   document.banner.src=images[i];
  }
  
 function backward() 
 {
  if (i <= 0) 
  {
   i = count - 1;
  } 
  else 
  {
   i--;
  }
  document.banner.src=images[i];
 }
  
 window.onload = function() 
 {
   slidingImages(),setInterval(slidingImages, 3000)
 };
```

```html
<center>
<p>
<img src="images/1.jpg" name="banner" id="name"/>
</p>
<input type="button" value="&laquo;prev" onClick="backward()"> 
<input type="button" value="next&raquo;" onClick="forward()">
</center>
```

What is the solution so my slideshow would be accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pause the automatic behavior when the mouse is within the red rectangle and continue in auto mode once the mouse is out of the red rectangle. The buttons of course work as expected.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    fieldset { width: -moz-fit-content; width: -webkit-fit-content; width: fit-content; border: 1px solid red; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
      <p>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" name="banner" id="name"/>
      </p>
      <fieldset id="control">
      <input id="prev" type="button" value="◄">
      <input id="next" type="button" value="►">
      </fieldset>
    </section>
    <script>
     var images = ["http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/1.jpg","http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/2.jpg","http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc487/myelstery/3.jpg"];

            var i = -1;
            var count = images.length; 
            var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
                var next = document.getElementById('next');
                var control = document.getElementById('control');
                var autoSlide;


            window.onload = auto;
                function auto() {
              autoSlide = setInterval(fwd, 3000)        };
                function pause() {
                    clearInterval(autoSlide);
                }

            function fwd() {

                if (i >= 0 && i < 2) 
                {
                    i += 1;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                document.banner.src=images[i];
            }

            function rev() {

                if (i > 0 && i <= 2) 
                {
                    i -= 1;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    i = 2;
                }
                document.banner.src=images[i];
            }

                prev.addEventListener('click', function() {

                    rev();
                }, false);

                next.addEventListener('click', function() { 
                  fwd();
                }, false);

                control.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

                    pause();
                }, false);

                control.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { 
                  auto();
                }, false);


                </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but i dont want to put stop and start functions. and also your previous function is not working.

Comment: >'your previous function is not working'. It works, but it doesn't go below 0, that could easily changed: `function rec() { ...... else { i = 2; }` Then you want the slideshow to always operate automatically? So the buttons are not for manual control but just for the direction?

Comment: yup. like when I press the next and previous it clear the timer and move forward or backward to the next picture and when im not pressing the forward and backward button it automatically moving forward to the next picture without affecting the timer

Comment: Did you follow the last comment?

Comment: yes and it works. can you implement for me when i click the forward and backward button it restart the timer so if the auto forward goes to the next picture when i click the forward button it wont affect each other?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to implement it.